# Does this summation identity hold?

Tags: summation

Suppose we have $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-N} f(n)$. Is this sum equal to $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} f(-n)$?

The reason why I ask this question is because I am trying to write $\sum_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)^3}$ as a summation of form $\sum_1^{\infty} $. Am I correct in my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have correctly rewritten that sum.  Your sum can therefore be rewritten as
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)^3} =  
-1 + 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)^3} +
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{-n}}{(2(-n)-1)^3}
$$

Comment: but isnt $(-1)^{-1} = -1 $ ??

Comment: Indeed, so you could simplify that last sum quite a bit

Comment: so, can we conclude that $(-1)^{-n} = 1 ? $

Comment: No, we can't. Try a few values of $n$ to check.